# Bulk edit orders to 'wc-processing' status

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, post-status

I searched for an answer but couldn't find any.

How can I allow bulk edit orders to `wc-processing` status?

Currently I can any other status but this one and it's making the work harder, making me go in each order and change one by one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code works to change to order status to processing:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
if ( ! empty( $order ) ) {
    $order->update_status( 'processing' );
}
```

So you'll need to query all orders by ID and use that code in a loop, like so:

```
$query = new WC_Order_Query( array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'return' => 'ids',
) );
$orders = $query->get_orders();
foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( ! empty( $order ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
```

This code is tested, but always backup your database first - just in case!

Comment: Where do I add this code?

Comment: I depends on how - and how often - you may want to change order status. If you just need to do this once, add the code snippet to your footer.php file, load the site once to run the code, then remove it. Done! Otherwise, you could wrap the code in a function, place that in your functions.php file and use it as needed. BTW, updated the code... I was updating the status to completed, but you wanted processing, so I changed it to $order->update_status( 'processing' );

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want to have an option to bulk change to 'processing' to the bulk options. How should I do it?

Comment: The code I put in my answer will do that - change all orders to "processing". If you are not looking for a programming solution, you can also bulk update your orders in the admin WooCommerce->Orders page - select all orders, then choose "Change status to processing" from the Bulk Actions dropdown. You should also temporarily turn off the "Processing order" email notifications in WooCommerce->Settings->Emails so the site doesn;t send out emails to all your customers.